# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently pulling my hair out solving this bug :/ I have already tried the solutions from other SO threads regarding this topic but had no luck so far.

Here's what's wrong:
I have a UINavigationController that pushes View A, from View A I can press a button to push View B - works fine. But when I push View B, then rotate the screen into landscape mode and then click the back button, I get the following output in the console and the view switching is not animated, just switches from B back to A:

```
2012-01-02 20:50:42.866 [13345:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DimensionConversionViewController: 0x68831f0>.
2012-01-02 20:50:42.868 [13345:f803] attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UINavigationController: 0x6b541a0> modalViewController = <UISnapshotModalViewController: 0x6da5190>
```

**This is how I push the View B into the stack:**

```
- (void) showConverter:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:converter animated:YES];
}
```

**-viewDidLoad of View B:**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateInterface) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
        // ... Update text fields ...
        [self updateInterface];
 }
```

**-viewDidUnload of View B:**

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}
```

If you have questions or need more code samples, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Check your `viewWillAppear:animated:`, `viewDidAppear:animated:`, `viewWillDisappear:animated:`, and `viewDidDisappear:animated:` methods.

Comment: These methods aren't implemented in both VCs. Should these methods be implemented in all view controllers that get pushed into the stack?

Comment: You don't have to implement them.  If you do, you have to call `super` in them.

Comment: Finally solved the issue, seems like this problem can have many different causes but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out that in my case the root cause of the problem was, that I forgot to update all the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` methods in the different view controllers to return YES for all `UIInterfaceOrientations` (or let's say they should all return the sam). Doing this solved the issue.

Comment: I was having similar weirdness and this answer saved me.  Right O!  This problem only seems to happen for in landscape on iOS 5.  This app has been running just fine in iOS 4 for several years.  It also seems like it only happens when building in Xcode 4.  Until recently we built using Xcode 3 and this never cropped up.

Comment: Genius!!! I had the same problem: In both view controllers I needed to return the same thing: `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` and it solved my problem as well.

Comment: Gosh! Had a hard time figuring this out! This helped me solve my problem too! iOS6 and XCode 4.6.